# FileDepot module help

Tags: 7, files

I am using FileDepot module, and I wanted some help in this. I wanted the authenticated users to create their own folder, and upload their files. They can upload files, but they cannot create their own folder. How do them give them the permission to create their folder?

I found a feature like LOCK. What is this lock feature basically used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the lock feature is to indicate that you are editing the manuscript. When you are ready editing, and have uploaded the next version, you can unlock it.